# Gnome-Clocks crashing on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, gnome-clocks

I have Ubuntu 20.04 with default Gnome desktop installed on my Thinkpad X240 laptop, it's a brand new installation. I installed gnome-clocks package using apt and tried running it, but it does not launch.

So tried launching from terminal and I get :

```
sumitb@sumitslaptop:~$ gnome-clocks

(org.gnome.clocks:86544): Gtk-WARNING **: 18:16:13.042: Theme parsing error: <broken file>:1:0: Failed to import: The resource at “/org/gnome/clocks/css/gnome-clocks.yaru.css” does not exist
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

This seems to be a dconf path but is ending in a css file, which is not usual for me.

Can anybody help?

Comment: same problem for me. you're not the only one. :(. I have another machine with 20.04 and on that one it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [known bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-clocks/+bug/1874405) with gnome-clocks, already reported on Launchpad.